# Where to put file in react-native project, so i can access it with react-native-fs (Android)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react-native project.
I have a file that i want to access using the react-native-fs library.
The file is called "chart.html", and i want to get its path with something like this:

```
'file://' + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/chart.html';
```

I have already tried putting the file in the root directory, android/app, android/app/src and android/app/src/main, without success so far.

Where do i put the file so the code from above works?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your files into the "**assets**" folder and **recompile** the Android-project, you will be able to access these files with [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs):

```
android/app/src/main/assets/
```

The following methods might help you to access them:

- [readDirAssets(dirpath: string): Promise](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readdirassetsdirpath-string-promisereaddiritem)
- [readFileAssets(filepath:string, encoding?: string): Promise](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfileassetsfilepathstring-encoding-string-promisestring)

You can also have a look at "**existsAssets**" and "**copyFileAssets**", the latter for putting the files into Document-Folder if other libraries shall work with the files without having access to the assets-folder itself.

Comment: How do I do it for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [react-native-asset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-asset) to put files to your project and access them with `require` keyword.

Example for file with path `./assets/html/chart.html`:

1. Add or modify `react-native.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
 project: {
   ios: {},
   android: {},
 },
 dependencies: {
 },
 assets: [
   './assets/html'
 ],
};
```

2. Run `npx react-native-asset`
3. Use the file:

```js
const file = require('./assets/html/chart.html')
```